# Why this works in JavaScript but TypeScript think it is invalid?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance

I tried to create a base class that has a static utility method to construct the class, which uses `return new this()`. But it doesn't work when I have a subclass extending it, because that utility method returns the base class instead of subclass, which is not the same as JavaScript.

Minimal Example:

```
class Base {
    static create() {
        return new this()
    }
}
class Sub extends Base {
    fn() {
        return this
    }
}
Sub.create().fn() // TypeScript error, JavaScript ok
Base.create().fn() // TypeScript error, JavaScript error
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8CwAoaXoQC5lwEthpgAnBAhACgEoUNsnoLcBXMgO2k4QHdouABaEIdRtgC+GaelCQYAZTYAjaAgAeuBJwAmMeBCRpM2AGac6DU8xYJ2XQSIgSss2cpUA6cpW10vCysAemDoABUATwAHBEVyQmjcdTIyAHsyABpoACkwADcweLJE5LSAa2gAfgBCDEMEHwoqAKD6UIiYuISklPSs3IKinuSEVIyMIA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because TypeScript doesn't have [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) types for static methods.  There's a longstanding open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863), asking for such a feature.  For now it's not part of the language, but luckily comments on that issue describe a workaround that should get you the behavior you're looking for:

```
class Base {
    static create<T extends Base>(this: new () => T) {
        return new this()
    }
}
```

Here we are making `create()` a [generic](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) method with a parameter of type `T extends Base` that can only be called on an object whose `this` context is a zero-arg constructor that returns a value of type `T`.

Therefore the compiler knows that `Sub.create()` will return a `Sub` and that `Base.create()` will return a `Base`:

```
Sub.create().fn() // okay
Base.create().fn() // Property 'fn' does not exist on type 'Base'
```

This also has the advantage over your existing code in that the following is an error now:

```
class Oops extends Base {
    x: string;
    constructor(x: string) {
        super();
        this.x = x.toUpperCase();
    }
}

Oops.create(); // error!
```

The `Oops` class does not have a zero-arg constructor, and so the implementation of `Oops.create()` will end up calling `new Oops()` without the required parameter and cause a runtime error when it tries to call `toUpperCase()` on `undefined`.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8CwAoaXoQC5lwEthpgAnBAhAHgBVoEAPXBAOwBMZ4IEA+AClwALQhABc0VggDu0fgEpoAXl7RaitJmzaKuAK5lWkmdGGiFGbQF8MN9KEgwAynoBGDZm05xEKS9gAzVgU-LW0sXQMjMwh-LDs7DBdXADpyShYFFKCQgHpc6AB7AGswAE8MbgQ0iiosnMV86AAFMkKABwQyXDLoAHIgvuh2QoQYVkLcD1Epwuiyzv6qvowMByhoAHkOmCYWDi5fTW1GCTwyQlYAcwBuONI5871gXEKyflOcXAvrjXvtCB6TrveR3MLhGIpRjKaCMFKvACq7WBAGFEAowdZbKt0Nt2hAahkEBjoE0um0yABCIA)